# How to make a Recursive Shape in java

Tags: java, recursion

how can I make a recursive shape like this one ?
this is an example of the user entered m = 3, n = 5
and the output will be like :

```
***
****
*****
*****
****
***
```

the Hint I have is:

> you CAN use a for loop to draw one, single row of the shape. But you need recursion to call the method on the “smaller” version of the problem

---

This is my code and it's totally wrong :|

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int m = s.nextInt();
    int n = s.nextInt();

    question1(m,n);
}

public static void question1(int m, int n){

    int counter = m;
    if(m < n){
        System.out.print("*");
        m = m + 1;
        question1(m,n);

    }

    else if(m == n){
        System.out.print("*");


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is the problem?

Comment: You should always start by doing some planning and then continue by trying to write code that implements your idea.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is my code ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one implementation.  I know recursion can be really hard to wrap your head around initially:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    printShape(3, 1);
}

// @param numStars The number of stars to print in a row
// @param inc +1 or -1, representing increasing or decreasing amount of stars
private static void printShape(final int numStars, final int inc) {
    if (numStars < 3) 
        return;
    else if (numStars > 5) 
        printShape(numStars - 1, -1); // Reverse directions
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++) 
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
        printShape(numStars + inc, inc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read about recursion and try to do something. This website/book has really good explanation.

[Java Recursion](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use return statement in  question1(int m, int n), and you need to call that function. This is an example of recursion.

```
public static long factorial(int n) { 
if (n == 1) return 1; 
return n * factorial(n-1); 
}
```